# can not separate csv file with thousands and comma

Tags: python, regex, csv, read-csv

I need to read  csv file with comma and also string and numbers but number contains comma in it like 1,260. Also csv file is seperated by comma so i can not read file in right way. How could i seperate them?

```
import pandas as pd
df_customer_list=pd.read_csv("Customer_list 09.01.2024.csv",sep=',')
```

the file contains below 3 rows

```
angel melo,angelmelo56@gmail.com,"1,260",Yes,0
michael alem,michaleloo@gmail.com,60,Yes,0
charles ekk,charles56@gmail.com,"2,220",Yes,0
```

Comment: What ended up in `df_ customer_list` after you executed the posted code?

Comment: `pd.read_csv("Customer_list 09.01.2024.csv", thousands=",", header=None)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the core issue is that your data does not appear to have a header so that makes display of the dataframe a little wonky.

Taking your example data, I seem to be able to load it ok by just specifying the thousands separator and no headers.

```py
import io
import pandas

data = """
angel melo,angelmelo56@gmail.com,"1,260",Yes,0
michael alem,michaleloo@gmail.com,60,Yes,0
charles ekk,charles56@gmail.com,"2,220",Yes,0
"""

df = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), thousands=",", header=None)
print(df)
```

Should produce:

```
              0                      1     2    3  4
0    angel melo  angelmelo56@gmail.com  1260  Yes  0
1  michael alem   michaleloo@gmail.com    60  Yes  0
2   charles ekk    charles56@gmail.com  2220  Yes  0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Specify the quote character to ensure proper parsing of fields with commas
df_customer_list = pd.read_csv("Customer_list 09.01.2024.csv", sep=',', quotechar='"')

# Optionally, convert the columns with numbers to integers or floats, if needed
# This step is required if you want to perform numerical operations on these fields
df_customer_list['number_column'] = df_customer_list['number_column'].str.replace(',', '').astype(int)

# Display the DataFrame
print(df_customer_list)
```

If your numbers are floating-point values, use astype(float) instead.

Comment: Is the default value for `quotechar` not `"`?

Comment: First option did not work and second option return error: "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!"

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
your_data = pd.read_csv("yourfile.csv", sep=",", thousands=',', decimal='.')
print(your_data)
```

Comment: it doesnt work :(

Comment: I checked it with the data you have provided. if you give me the specific data I will check it for you.